# Leaflet js: How to get Lat and lng at the end of drawing any marker on Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i got a one code which is close but i am not sure because i am first time working with Leaflet js.

my intention is: suppose Leaflet js is showing map or non geographical data and i have one Leaflet js related toolbar. toolbar has many marker like circle, poly, square etc. when user click on any marker on toolbar to start drawing on map then when drawing of marker will be finish then how do i know?

how could i attach a function which will work as callback for drawing finish and the function also let me know the  Lat and lng of marker. if i know the  Lat and lng then i can save in db and later we can reuse it to draw the shape.

### the below code i got

```
var map = L.map('mapcanvas').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

map.on('click', function(e){
    // Place marker
    var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);

    // Ajax query to save the values:
    var data = {
        lat: e.latlng.lat,
        lng: e.latlng.lng
    }

    // saving lat and lng to db by ajax call
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(data);
});
```

please have a look at the code and i am not sure does it solve my purpose because here the code work with click event with map.

so when we click on map then marker drawing would be complete. so please read my post and understand what i am looking for and suggest me with best idea how to achieve it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you're using to draw polygons/shapes. If you're using leaflet.draw, you would do something like:

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    var points = JSON.stringify(e.layer.toGeoJSON());
});
```

And then saving points to your database.

Read the leaflet.draw [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw), it's pretty complete and straightforward.

Comment: what the above line is doing? what it is drawing ?

Comment: It isn't drawing anything, it's a callback for when a new shape is added to map via leaflet.draw

Comment: any article exist which show me how to use leaflet.draw to draw circle, square etc on map and also when drawing will finish then a callback function will tell me shape name and lat lng etc.

Comment: I've edited my original response with a link do leaflet.draw docs. It has all the information you need, including code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
        var latlngs = e.layer['_latlngs'];
        console.log(latlngs)
    });
```

if Rectangle
output:

```
0: Object { lat: 51.50084993084658, lng: -0.05254515762210588 }
1: Object { lat: 51.52007317336922, lng: -0.05254515762210588 }
2: Object { lat: 51.52007317336922, lng: 0.006832403235339513 }
3: Object { lat: 51.50084993084658, lng: 0.006832403235339513 }
```