# How do I supply different options for each layer created with L.GeoJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I need to add a different class to each `<path>` element everytime [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) is loading the data geometry from geojson and draws the polygon.

Is there a callback for it?

I found these links: [Layer loaded](https://github.com/JasonSanford/leaflet-vector-layers/pull/20/commits/a97c5627c16d6f48635de602743804ba20cddf8c) and [draw created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193640/leaflet-js-how-to-get-lat-and-lng-at-the-end-of-drawing-any-marker-on-map)

But i need to add a different class to its `<path>` each time one is created by loading the coordinates from the geojson.

Tried this:

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');
});
```

And this:

```
function myCallBack(e) {
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');
}

map.on('layeradd', myCallBack);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for callbacks or events. Look at the [`className` option for all paths](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#path-classname).

The question you should be asking is "How can I add a custom class to the SVG elements representing Leaflet polygons?" and not "What callbacks of events does Leaflet fire when a polygon is loaded?". This is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and I suggest you try to avoid that in the future.

See a [working demo](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/kof/edit?html,output), inspect the SVG path yourself.

Comment: That gives a the same class to all path elements tho, what if i wanted a different class for each path?

Comment: Ask the right question. If you are using `L.GeoJSON`, the question is "How do I supply different options for each layer created with `L.GeoJSON`?"

Comment: Ok i have updated the title, thank you :) Do you have an idea of how i could achieve that?

Comment: The answer lies within the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorials](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html)